# add X-XSRF-TOKEN to dropzone.js angular

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using angular wrapper for dropzone.js taken from this http://www.cantangosolutions.com/blog/Easy-File-Upload-Using-DropzoneJS-AngularJs-And-Spring 
example.

What is the way to add csrf-token in angular dropzone.js?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
dropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
        var csrftoken = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
        data.append('_csrf', csrftoken);
};
```